# Compute cosine similarity in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cosine-similarity

I have a dataset like that (with large dimension)

```
   id_brand id_member
    1        100
    2        105
    1        106
    3        100
```

and I want to compute cosine similarity between the different brands.
The formula is the the following

{\displaystyle \cos \theta ={\frac {\mathbf {A} \cdot \mathbf {B} }{|\mathbf {A} ||\mathbf {B} |}}}.

I tried to pivot in pyspark but it's complicated so I want to do in sql (redhisft) but I don't have idea to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Explain the formula for cosine similarity.  Such functions are not built-into a database.  I'm not interested in looking up the formula -- and I might be more interested than most people in the question.

Comment: Also indicate where you are stuck in conceiving how to do this. I assume you've become familiar with how to compute cosine similarity over some data. Are you thinking of using SQL because you think it will be straightforward? Your comment implies this may be the case. Maybe an X-Y problem. What form is this data in originally?